# Get Adsense revenue on Android

Tags: android, google-api, adsense, adsense-api

I'm new to android dev. I'm currently try to implement app, querying adsense revenue.

I found [AdSense Management API v1.1 (Rev. 18) 1.7.2-beta](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/adsense/v1.1/index.html).

The question is: is it possible to get revenue with API browser key and are there any samples (as there is no samples in this library)?

Comment: Totally as an aside, don't add ads that your users will hate.  So many times, I've seen an app that was great ruined by intrusive ads.

Comment: you got me wrong. I want to create app, that will retrieve my adsense revenue(I have two sites with adsense)

Comment: What do you mean "retrieve"? do you want your app to tell you what the revenue is, or be able to "withdraw" it?

Comment: ok ;D  Glad this was all just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Java command-line sample for the AdSense Management API](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/java/v1.x) and an [Android sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/android). Both use the [Java client library for Google APIs](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client).

For a quick overview on how to get started with the AdSense Management API and the Java client library, you can check [this client library guide](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Im not sure do I need to use OAuth or I can just use API key? There are no guide for using api key only. As far as I understand I need to grant OAuth access to my account and I dont want it

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to use OAuth, since you'll be accessing protected user data (even if it's your own). It's not so bad if you have a good library to help you, though :)